# Iterate over subscriber

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngfor

I'm having a bit of a problem understanding the observer / subscriber model and looping through that return.

So I've got a cocktail component that grabs an array of cocktail objects.

The core of <kbd>cocktail.service.ts</kbd>:

```
constructor(private _http: Http) {

}
// Returns an array of cocktail objects, using .map to json them
getCocktails() {
    return this._http.get(this._geturl)
        .map(res => res.json());
}
```

And the relevant bits of <kbd>cocktail.component.ts</kbd>:

```
// Calls the cocktail service and gets the json array
constructor(private _cocktailService: CocktailService) {
    this.cocktails = _cocktailService.getCocktails();
}
```

Now I understand that I can loop over the `cocktails` using:

```
<li *ngFor="let cocktail of cocktails | async">
```

But I'm just trying to understand how I would do that by using a subscribe method on the observer:

```
constructor(private _cocktailService: CocktailService) {
    this.cocktails = _cocktailService.getCocktails().subscribe(
        res => this.cocktails = res
    );
}
```

Now I can't use the async pipe, as essentially that does the subscribe for me, but if I use:

```
<li *ngFor="let cocktail of cocktails">
```

I just get an error. How do I subscribe, and loop through the return?

The error I'm getting is:

> core.umd.js:3004 EXCEPTION: Error in app/cocktail.template.html:3:5
>   caused by: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of
>   type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as
>   Arrays.

Comment: what error are you getting? adding the error could help us understand better!

Comment: Just added - thanks

Comment: Create a interface for that json result set and use it likes this in service  return this.http.get(dataUrl)
            .map(response => response.json() as IFacility[])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a interface for your json result set and map it in service like this.

```
return this.http.get(dataUrl) 
.map(response => response.json() as ICocktail[]);
```

and in the component create a type of that interface and use it to map with the response from service like the below code.

```
cocktails: ICocktail[];

 this.cocktails = _cocktailService.getCocktails().subscribe(
        res => this.cocktails = res
    );
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you `.subscribe()` you get a `Subscription` which is not compatible with `|async` because it can't be subscribed to.
If you use for example `.map()` you get an `Observable` that you can use with `| async`

```
constructor(private _cocktailService: CocktailService) {
    this.cocktails = _cocktailService.getCocktails().map(
        res => this.cocktails = res
    );
}
```